# D3: How to add a margin between min/max from data and min/max from axis?

Tags: d3.js

How can I add some space between the min/max values and my min/max axis values?

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ftgbhyqj/21/.

As you can see the min and max values are always used for the min/max on the y axis. How can I add some extra space, like 5% of the available height, between my max value from the data and the max value on the y axis?

See the following screenshot. Between the maximum from the data and the maximum available chart area is some extra space.

[image: screenshot]

I'm not talking about `margin.top` or `margin.bottom` since this would also make the axis smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's best to manipulate the scale domains directly rather than rely on the `d3.extent()` function alone: https://jsfiddle.net/wmLd3r8z/. You can probably do something cleaner on the x axis with the time series data, but hopefully this gives you what you need.

```
const x_extent = d3.extent(data, d => d.ts);

const x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([x_extent[0] -1000, x_extent[1] + 1000])
    .range([0, w]);

const y_extent = d3.extent(data, d => d.value);
const y_extent_diff = 0.05 * Math.abs(y_extent[1] - y_extent[0]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([y_extent[0] - y_extent_diff, y_extent[1] + y_extent_diff])
    .range([h, 0])
```

Comment: I tried to apply this answer to my code but it seems to keep getting pushed to the bottom. https://codepen.io/lahesty/pen/zLywLj?editors=0011 (lines 126-131) What might be wrong?