# Create a padding for the first and last data points using a time scale

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I would like to create a buffer between my smallest/largest data points and the axes, so that *upon initial load* and before zoom you can see the entire min/max dot and it won't be cut off. My code Pen is at : https://codepen.io/lahesty/pen/XYoyxV (lines 119-141)

I believe that has something to do with scaling? Here's what I have currently. Perhaps I can adjust either the range or domain to give it a little more space before the user zooms. Here is what I have:

```
// scale, set ranges

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0, width-100])
.domain(d3.extent(data[0], function(d) { return d.inspected_at; }));

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.range( [height, 0])
.domain(d3.extent(data[0], function(d) { return d.flow_data; }));

//create x and y axis

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
.scale(x)
.ticks((width+2)/(height+2))
.tickSize(-height)
.tickPadding(10)    
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %d, %H:%M:%S"))

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
.scale(y)
.ticks(5)
.tickSize(-(width-100))
.tickPadding(10)
```

Thanks so much! Let me know if I can provide any more info

Edit: *Edit* this is different from the possible duplicate answer in that scaling time is a different function of d3 than just a normal number/digit. See answer below (interval.offset)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729682/d3-how-to-add-a-margin-between-min-max-from-data-and-min-max-from-axis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3: How to add a margin between min/max from data and min/max from axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729682/d3-how-to-add-a-margin-between-min-max-from-data-and-min-max-from-axis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a time scale, you cannot simply multiply the domain values by a given number, as the answer linked in the comments correctly does (which is the most common solution for a linear scale).

In a time scale, you can add or subtract time using `interval.offset`.

For instance, in your case, I'll subtract 10 seconds from the first date and add 10 seconds in the last date:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([d3.timeSecond.offset(d3.min(data[0], function(d) {
            return d.inspected_at;
        }), -10),
        d3.timeSecond.offset(d3.max(data[0], function(d) {
            return d.inspected_at;
        }), +10)
    ])
    .range([0, width - 100]);
```

That should be enough, but you can change that magic number the way you want.

Also, it's worth mentioning that `interval.offset` is way easier and handier than the JS alternatives, since you can use `d3.timeSecond` for seconds, `d3.timeMinute` for minutes, `d3.timeDay` for days and so on, adding or subtracting the necessary amount of seconds, minutes, days, weeks etc you want.

Here is the updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBEyrN?editors=0010

Comment: You can do the percent trick by using `Date.getMilliseconds()` for the domain borders, add-subtract an amount and convert back with `new Date(millisec)`

Comment: Which ends up just validating what I said: OP cannot just multiply the domain value by a given number. Besides that, `interval.offset` is way more convenient and handy.

Comment: How might I use that same process for my y axis? Is there a way to use interval.offset for number, not a time? https://codepen.io/lahesty/pen/zLywLj?editors=0011 (lines 126-131) Lines seem to keep getting shrunk to the bottom. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: @LaurenAH for the y axis, since that's just a linear scale, use the solution in the answer linked in the comments.

Comment: Hence my question, I graphed it as the answer specified, still having issues with it appearing squished at the bottom, hm

Comment: @LaurenAH In that case, please post a new question, with all the details. Here at S.O. we should keep one issue per question. Also, it's worth mentioning that 5% of 2 is a very low number, let's try 20%: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxRymK?editors=0011